# How to automatically transform Abs[Cos[x]]Sec[x] to Sign[Cos[x]]?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

Out of some simplification, the term `Abs[Cos[x]]Sec[x]` appears.

How can I make the code automatically transform `Abs[Cos[x]]Sec[x]` to `Sign[Cos[x]]`?

Comment: he problem seems to be that `Cos[Pi/2]=0` and herefore the `Sec` is infinite. You have to exclude `Pi/2` from the domain

Comment: If this term came out of a call to `Simplify` or `FullSimplify`, take a look at [`TransformationFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunctions.html).

Comment: `FullSimplify[Abs[f[x]]/f[x]]` works, so I suspect it's the autosimplification of `1/Cos[x]` to `Sec[x]` -- or, rather, that `Sec[x]` is not treated like `1/Cos[x]` in all transformations.

Comment: Not a great way to do it: `Block[{Cos = Hold[Cos], Sec = 1/Hold[Cos][#] &}, 
 ReleaseHold@FullSimplify[Abs[Cos[x]] Sec[x]]]`

Comment: To extend @Chip's comment: Try `TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, # /. 
    Sec[t_] :> 1/(Abs[Cos[t]] Sign[Cos[t]]) &}`